# How can I select an XML element if there are three of the same elements there?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Given this [XML found here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser=34).

How can I get each contact item individually?

For example, say I wanted to get only twitter:

I tried this:

```
return doc.XPathSelectElement("/ipb/profile/contactinformation/contact[type/text() = 'LinkedIn']/value").Value;
```

But that returns nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/test/contactinfo/contact[type = 'Twitter']/address`

If that doesn't work, try

`/test/contactinfo/contact[type/text() = 'Twitter']/address`

Comment: Given your new XML, the appropriate XPath is `//contact[title='Twitter']/value`.

Comment: Sergio, you could easily have figured this out yourself by analogy, although Porges was nice enough to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var profile = doc.Root.Element("profile");

var contactinfo = profile.Element("contactinformation");

var contacts = from contact in contactinfo.Elements("contact")
               where (string)contact.Element("title") == "Twitter"
               select contact;

var result = (string)contacts.Single().Element("value");
```